# How to delete session from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8

I am trying to store session in the database rather than in file.
So in my .env file:-

> SESSION_DRIVER=database

&
in my config/session.php:-

> 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'), 'table' => 'sessions',

So now after doing:

> $request->session()->flush()

to remove session in my controller, the session values are stilled stored in my DB. Although after flushing session in the controller I have checked session key exists or not where it is showing session does not exist, but **why session are not deleted from DB?** Also in my DB table *sessions* **user_id** is showing **NULL**. **Why is that?**

Earlier I used to store session in a file. Now I am trying to store session in database. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What are you storing in the session? the visitor's information has to remain in session and the `user_id` is null because you're not authenticated

Answer (score 3):

Old session rows in database will be deleted only after the ***Session garbage collector*** is called, the specific function is `gc()`.

This function has a probability to be called on every request, you can control the chances it will run with the `session.lottery` config value.

But do not worry, even if the session rows are still present in the database they are invalidated after logout (`user_id` is null), only deletion occur with the `gc()` function above.

Nor `Session::flush()` nor `Session::regenerate(true)` will delete old session rows.